# SQL Server export to CSV fails when imported to same table on a new server

Tags: sql-server, import

1. On a SQL Server 2008, I did a `Script to... CREATE to...` to capture a table definition. The table is mostly `nchar` columns
2. On a new server I ran that script to recreate the table
3. On the original server I did `SELECT *...` followed by a `Save to...` CSV
4. On the new server I used `Import Data...` on the CSV

The import fails with many errors relating to truncation and conversions. That is very interesting, it should be valid given they have the same definition?

I have tried many things - telling it to ignore these errors reduces the number of errors to two, but still fails to import. Telling it to import to a new table instead of the existing CREATED one fails with the same errors (!!!).

Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: Why not save a ton of steps and use the built in data export/import tool?

Comment: First, try @SeanLange 's proposal. Also, check that the COLLATION for both Servers & Databases is the same. Otherwise you will suffer several problems with SP's, Views, etc

Comment: Bookmark Erland's main page after reading his discussion of ETL [here](http://www.sommarskog.se/bulkload.html). BCP would be safer, faster, and repeatable.

Comment: @Maury , do any of the fields in the exported table contain text fields longer than 255? If so, when the data is exported and you want to import into another server, the import process is probably has a max of 255 for the text fields and any values longer that 255 my generate errors.

Comment: @EdMendez - yeah but the databases should be identical in terms of field defs, so if there is one of these it should also be in the destination. I am going to try SMor's suggestion and report back when I get a chance.

Answer (score 0):

OMG! Somewhere in the bowels of the MS software stack, it inserted those three magic characters at the start of the file that indicated it was unicode.

So it was changing the first field name to include illegal chars, and then everything after that was buggered. I only found this when I went *back* to the preview after defining the column mappings and then saw that the "from" field suddenly had gibberish!

Well, at least it took less time than watching "[Real Men](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Men_(film))", so I can't even complain about the part of my life I wont get back.